Setting up VimTeX with forward search in WSL2
ive got neovim with VimTeX installed on WSL2 Ubuntu. LaTeX Compilation works well but using :VimtexView to open the pdf shows the error 'Viewer cannot find Zathura windows ID'
I have vcsrv installed on windows, but when i launch a GUI app it opens but vcsrv says 0 clients and my config looks like this:
vimtex config: vim.g.vimtex_view_method = 'zathura'
zathurarc: set synctex true
set synctex-editor-command 'nvim --headless +"%{line}G%{column}l" "%{input}"'
latexmkrc: $pdflatex = 'pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 %O %S';
